# Rearrange Workspaces in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, gnome, workspaces, workspace-switcher

In Ubuntu 20.04, how can we rearrange/reorder the workspaces?

For example, when I press the Windows key on my keyboard, I get this view of all my workspace on the right of my screen. How can I swap the positions of the topmost workspace with the 2nd topmost workspace?

[image]

Comment: GitLab issues created, requested [with shortcuts](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/-/issues/4023) and [drag and drop](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/-/issues/4022) ([original issue on Bugzilla](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=646409))

Answer (score 5):

There is an extension that allows you to reorder workspaces.

[Reorder Workspaces](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/3685/reorder-workspaces/)